# Removing the first and only the first '-' in the values of a string column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
               1          2
0    ADRC-111-01    ADRC111
1  ADRC-11955-01  ADRC11955
2  ADRC-18133-01  ADRC18133
3    SWAN0023-03   SWAN0023
```

In Column 1, I wish to get rid of the first `-` sign, regardless of how many are in the the cell. There are one or two `-` in each entry.

Desired output:

```
              1          2
0    ADRC111-01    ADRC111
1  ADRC11955-01  ADRC11955
2  ADRC18133-01  ADRC18133
3    SWAN002303   SWAN0023
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `.str.replace` with `n=1`:

```
df['1'] = df['1'].str.replace('-', '', n=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> df
              1          2
0    ADRC111-01    ADRC111
1  ADRC11955-01  ADRC11955
2  ADRC18133-01  ADRC18133
3    SWAN002303   SWAN0023
```

Comment: thank you so much! worked!